# Search vector of objects by object data member attribute

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a Jukebox simulator and I'm trying to search a vector of Album objects by album title and return the index for use in other functions. The function is to be used for a number of different things such as deleting an album, printing an album etc.

I have gotten it to work in a previous application when the function was in the same Class as the data member to search for. I can however for some reason not get it to work using getters. No matter what I input as search key the idx returns 3 although the vector only contains indexes 0, 1 and 2 (only 3 albums right now).
The lambda function seem to be able to access data by using the getAlbum()-getter but somehow the comparison doesn't work.

My approach might be entirely wrong and I'd be grateful for any pointers in the right direction, or suggestions on how to accomplish the desired result using some other technique.

```
int Jukebox::findAlbumIdx(string key)
{
    // Get search predicate
    auto it = find_if(albvec.begin(), albvec.end(), [key](Album const &a)
    {
        return (a.getAlbum() == key);
    });

    int idx = it - albvec.begin();

    return idx;
}

void Jukebox::delAlbum()
{
    cin.get();
    string key;

    cout << "Input title of album to delete: ";
    getline(cin, key);

    int idx = findAlbumIdx(key);

    if(idx > albvec.size() - 1)
        cout << "No hits." << endl;
    else
        albvec.erase(albvec.begin() + idx);
}
```

getAlbum is just a simple inline getter as such:

```
string getAlbum() const {return album_title;}
```

Following Jonathan Wakely's suggestion to add `std::cout << a.getAlbum() << " == " << key << std::endl;` in the lambda the output is this:

```
Input title of album to delete: Abbey Road
 == Abbey Road
 == Abbey Road
 == Abbey RoadLonely Hearts Club Band
No hits.
```

Obviously the getter isn't actually getting much to use for comparison. Not sure why it only gets the last entry and on the right hand side of the comparison.

If I add this to any of the functions above it gets and displays the Album titles correctly. The vector seems to be fine just before calling `findAlbumIdx(key);` and also inside the `findAlbumIdx` function.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < albvec.size(); ++i)
    cout << albvec[i].getAlbum() << endl;
```

Comment: Think about what will happen if the album can't be found. What will [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) return then? How will it work when calculating the index then?

Comment: In the code you have shown, there is no need for the index. So you could just use the iterator returned by `find_if`. But you could also look into using a structure designed for faster look-up, such as `std::map` or `std::unorderd_map`.

Comment: We also need to see the code for `Album::getAlbum()`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, `std::distance` is good in generic code, but if you know you have RandomAccessIterators then what advantage does it have over simple subtraction to find the difference?

Comment: @JonathanWakely `std::distance` self documents the code and that is already a good point for it over a `operator-`.

Comment: Updated to show Album::getAlbum(). It seems to be working properly in every other place where I use it.

Comment: @galop1n, subtraction of RandomAccessIterators is also self-documenting if you understand pointers :)

Comment: `int idx = ` should be self-documenting enough. Proper naming goes a long way towards self-documenting code.

Comment: By the way, you know that the string equality operator is *case sensitive*? See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

Comment: @Jonathan a word like `distance` catch the eye more than a single character, it is the same for a `for_each` over a manual loop ( less true with range based now ). It is still mainly opinion based :)

Comment: Either use a debugger and break in the lambda, or add `std::cout << a.getAlbum() << " == " << key << std::endl;` to the lambda, so you can see what's being compared.

Comment: To me, it looks like your vector has been trashed somehow. How do you create and populate it? Are you sure that you're not using a `Jukebox` that has been destroyed?

Comment: I create the vector by reading the contents from a text file. By printing it from the 2 functions in the main question it seems to be fine though, with the correct data in the correct member fields etc. Somehow getAlbum() in the lambda function is not getting anything.

Comment: The `string` returned from `getline` has a `'\n'` at the end, none of your album names do.

Comment: Oh my god! The original playlist file had dos newlines (cause the creator of the file is running Windows and Visual Studio), after converting it using `dos2unix` (since I'm running Linux) the search is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original playlist file that is read into the vector to be searched had dos newlines, after converting it using `dos2unix` (since I'm running Linux) the search, and I presume a lot of other things, is working correctly.

I suppose trimming newline characters while reading the file into the vector would be the more correct approach.